# My function for checking perfect squares does not work, but its components work individually

Tags: python, function, integer, boolean, complex-numbers

Here is my function.

```
def is_square(n):    
    x = n ** 0.5
    return((x >= 0) & (x % 1 == 0))
```

When I run

```
is_square(-1)
```

I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-183-33fbc4575bf6>", line 1, in <module>
    is_square(-1)

  File "<ipython-input-182-32cb3317a5d3>", line 3, in is_square
    return((x >= 0) & (x % 1 == 0))

TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'complex' and 'int'
```

However, the individual components of this function work perfectly.

```
x = -1 ** 0.5

x >= 0
Out[185]: False

x % 1 == 0
Out[186]: True

(x >= 0) & (x % 1 == 0)
Out[189]: False
```

Why is my function not working?

Comment: That is not equivalent. It's `(-1) ** 0.5` in your program, not `-1 ** 0.5`. `(-1)**0.5` is a complex number which supports different operations from real numbers.

Comment: What do you think should be the result when you take the square root of `-1`? What do you expect to happen when you compare that to 0? Where the error message read `not supported between instances of 'complex' and 'int'`, do you in fact understand what `'complex'` means here? It seems like you might actually have a math theory question, not a programming question.

Comment: Understood - thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing in your function is defining x as `sqrt(n)`.
For `n = -1` that means x = *i* (meaning `sqrt(-1)`) so the `>=` expression has no real meaning.
When you test that part of your function individually, the code is being read as `-(1**0.5)`.
You'll see that when you rewrite it as `(-1)**(0.5)` it won't work anymore.